# jQuery UI - how to calculate custom values for draggable's "Containment"? jsfiddle added

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a small container and a large, variable-sized (the image is user-submitted) image inside it that I want to be draggable. I'm using jQuery UI's "draggable" feature for vertical dragging and it works well, but the only problem I'm having is that you can drag the image far up or down enough so that its edges show and you can see blank space above or below it in the container. I want it to work so that when, for example, the bottom edge of the image hits the bottom border of the container, you can't drag it up any further.

I'm trying to use the

```
{ containment:[x1, y1, x2, y2] }
```

option to make this work, and after a lot of trial and error I can calculate the correct values for differently-sized images, but I can't figure out a functional relationship between the image size and what the containment values. Can anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction as to what kind of relationship image size and containment should have? The container is a fixed size of 360x240. Thanks so much.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ey74c/ I don't want any of the white space within the container to show - i.e. you can't drag the image far enough up or down to let that happen. I tried setting containment: "parent" and it no longer scrolls?

Comment: Can you post some jsFiddle which show your problem?

Comment: Do you want to crop image like this ? : http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail

Comment: I don't want to crop it - I'm doing a preview functionality (like FB's cover photo where you can reposition the image before saving it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you should use: `{ containment:[x1, y1, x2, y2] }`

```
$("#container img").draggable({
    containment: [(parseInt($("#myImage").width()) - parseInt($("#container").width())) * -1, 
                  (parseInt($("#myImage").height()) - parseInt($("#container").height())) * -1, 0, 0]
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey74c/6/)

`x1` = - (img.width - container.width)

`y1` = - (img.height - container.height)

`x2` = 0

`y2` = 0

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately although it works on jsfiddle it doesn't work in my actual code...time to do some debugging :)

Comment: @user1436111 You welcome. Mark the answer as accepted or/and upvote it if it was helpful. I strongly suggest you to make sure you have good selectors to your elements. Browser's developer tools can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` ro your image and use `containment` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Ey74c/2/

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="myImage" src="http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg"
    />
</div>

$("#container img").draggable({
    containment: [$('#myImage').width() * -1, $('#myImage').height() * -1, 0, 0]
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for me - the problem is that you can drag it up or down far enough so that blank whitespace from the container shows. I want it to stop dragging before that happens.